# how to return a tuple of generators from generator input

Tags: python, generator

I want a function that works on a generator to also return a tuple of generators after a specified operation. Specifically, I want a function that takes input `gen1` and returns `gen1` and another generator returned by `returnsGenerator`.

I am typing two versions of the function. Which one of these would return a tuple of generators? If both of them return the same thing, then I guess the second is better since it does not need the `izip`?

```
def version1(gen1):
    return izip(gen1, returnsGenerator(gen1))

def version2(gen1):
    return gen1, returnsGenerator(gen1)
```

Comment: Do both functions work? How do you measure "better"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`version1` returns an iterator of tuple.

`version2` returns a tuple of generators